# unable to delete the report in salesforce org

Tags: reporting

I am trying to delete the report, but I am getting following error

> The report definition is obsolete. Your administrator has disabled all
>   reports for the custom object, or its relationships have changed.

Why am I getting this error? How can I work around it?

Comment: The error seems to be making perfect sense to me. As it says, there might be some changes to the object/fields that are being used in that report or may be report type. Have you tried to open the report customization page and see what all objects/fields are being used? Also did you try Googling the error?

Comment: I googled it, but every post says if there is any change in relationship field , we get this error, but i did not get the workaround for this issue. Yes I have changed the relationship fields & now my reports are absolete reports. So I need to delete these reports.

Comment: First thing I would do is: Customize report >> Remove Modified Fields(From Filter criteria/Data range/Column Headers/Show Fields area/Any formula fields that are accessing the modified fields. Also check with the custom report type(used by report you wanted to delete) for the modified fields.

Comment: I can not run the report, edit the report & delete the report and also I have not created any custom report type for reporting

Answer (score 0):

Did you recently change a Lookup field type to Master-Detail, or vice-versa? If so, the only solution is to revert that change and then you can delete the affected reports. [Vote on this Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bq9pAAC).